# using countif function, incorrect answers given

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use the following  countif formula for a row in a spreadsheet as follows

=COUNTIF(C6962:K6962,"Y")/(COUNTIF(C6962:K6962,"N")+COUNTIF(C6962:K6962,"Y"))

another part of the line has the formula
=COUNTIF(M6962:U6962,"y")/(COUNTIF(M6962:U6962,"n")+COUNTIF(M6962:U6962,"y"))

and the total for the whole line is
=COUNTIF((C6962:K6962):(M6962:U6962),"y")/(COUNTIF((C6962:K6962):(M6962:U6962),"n")+COUNTIF((C6962:K6962):(M6962:U6962),"y"))

What I am trying to count is the number of Y's and N's in the above cell ranges. If I have 3x Y's and 1x N the answers I would expect to show for the percentage is 75.0% and for fraction 3/4. However, what I am getting for percentage is 40% and for the fraction I get 1. what is wrong?

If the cell fraction gives me 1/2 when it should be for eg 4/8 I change the fraction to custom and manually alter the figure to 4/8

Why is excel not calculating the correct % and fraction figures? 
Hope someone can help

Murray

Comment: 1. "(C6962:K6962):(M6962:U6962)" this is not a valid range in Excel. You can't use colon (:) multiple times.

Comment: 2. "However, what I am getting for percentage is 40% and for the fraction I get 1. what is wrong?" without knowing your data and the exact formula (which one of the three) it is impossible to tell what's wrong.

Comment: 3. "If the cell fraction gives me 1/2 when it should be for eg 4/8" how Excel should know which is your desired format?

Comment: Try function validator in excel. It can help you to find a position of faults in your formulas. It is very useful feature. I used it for years to investigate more complex formulas. Best regards, Lukas

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(C6962:K6962,"Y"), COUNTIF(M6962:U6962,"Y"))/SUM(COUNTIF(C6962:K6962,{"N","Y"}), COUNTIF(M6962:U6962,{"N","Y"}))
```

If L6962 cannot ever be *Y* or *N* then this should do,

```
 =COUNTIF(C6962:U6962, "Y")/SUM(COUNTIF(C6962:U6962, {"N","Y"}))
```

If it is possible for L6962 to be *Y* or *N* then maybe this,

```
 =SUM(COUNTIF(C6962:U6962, "Y"), -COUNTIF(L6962, "Y"))/SUM(COUNTIF(C6962:U6962, {"N","Y"}), -COUNTIF(L6962, {"N","Y"}))
```

Note that you will still receive a `#DIV/0!` error if there are no *N* or *Y* in C6962:K6962 or M6962:U6962.

Answer (score 0):

*You need to use this method to get correct result:*

[image]

- Formula in Cell `K104`:

  `=COUNTIF($C$103:$K$103,"Y")/COUNTA($C$103:$K$103)`
- Formula in Cell `K105`:

`=COUNTIF($C$103:$K$103,"N")/COUNTA($C$103:$K$103)`

- Apply `Percentage Cell Format` on both Cells.

**N.B.**

- Use same formula to get result as *Fraction*, also apply `Faction Cell Format`.

*Adjust cell reference in the formula as needed.*